# How do I find out which files a user has open on a shared computer?

Tags: windows, network-shares, control-panel

In Windows, say I go into `Control Panel->Computer Management` and take a look at the 
 `Computer Management (Local)->Shared Folders->Sessions`.

I know that if anyone shows up in this list, they likely have a file open on my computer, denoted by the 
 `# Open Files` column.  But my question is, how do I tell which files that person has open?

Comment: its for questions like so that privileges are called privileges. if you doubt someone enough to not give them access, don't give it.

Comment: There might be an easier way, but Microsoft (formerly Sysinternals) [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) will tell you what files each process has opened, and which user started the process.

Comment: @Znau it's not a problem with unauthorized access, it's a problem of having too many windows open on one computer, saving a file to the other computer, and then not know which file to close to disconnect the laptop and take it with me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the same place you mentioned in your question (Control Panel->Computer Management->Shared Folders), but this time go to Open Files instead of Sessions and do a sort on the Accessed by column. Then just lookup the user you want and see the open files, one after another. You will also get some extra info in the other columns.